# PHP include_once and Adobe DreamWeaver Code Hinting

Tags: php, dreamweaver

So,

I am very fond of having code hinting in the development IDEs like what we get in Eclipse, FlashBuilder and Dreamweaver.

Now While working on PHP with Dreamweaver i found a simple `include_once` with upward directory reference has its consequences while we have `includes with in includes`.

so the solution i got is to use

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

With this i need to translate my

```
include_once '../../utils.php';
```

to

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'../../utils.php';
```

Now with this the problem is solved on the server.

But my Adobe Dreamweaver IDE is crying because a simple `include_once` is able to identify the file import and all the `CODE HINTING` is worked fine. After this change DreamWeaver no longer able to detect the files because they become dynamic imports.

To face the situation where i eagerly like to work in an intelligent environment i had to find a way that both server and IDE should work to my expectations.

This is what i ended doing.

```
if(!include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../libs/utils.php'){
    include_once '../../libs/utils.php';
}
```

With this the condition will never fail to go inside and server will work fine.
and the inside include will feed IDE to recognize the file so the code hinting will work.

MY QUESTIONS:

- ARE THERE ANY OTHER GOOD SOLUTIONS FOR MY EXPECTATIONS.
- WHAT WILL BE THE CONSEQUENCES USING `includes` WITH CONDITIONS.

Comment: I was forced to use Dreamweaver with PHP once, then I found NetBeans IDE which runs on Windows AND Linux - just stop what you're doing and use NetBeans and say goodbye to Dreamweaver - seriously dreamweaver doesn't support PHP Classes like NetBeans will and give you want you want / are used to with syntax highlighting plus a boat load of plugins (community driven unlike dreamweaver)

Comment: @dirt thanks for the suggestion. let me see NB.. I am familiar with JavaFx on it.

Comment: hey @dirt NetBeans IDE is cool. For my above issue it suited well. Now i got another (this time in NB)..

Comment: hey @dirt NetBeans IDE is cool. For my above issue it suited well. Now i got another (this time in NB).. The CLASS(A) properties can be accessed if it is initialized in the same PHP document. But If the Same CLASS(A) is initialized in another CLASS(B). Now while accessing CLASS(A)'s instance via CLASS(B) in a PHP document doesn't give the CodeCompletion when I type $instanceofclassB->instanceofa->. NB fail to understand the object type of 'instanceofa' while Dreamweaver is good in this case. Did you got any idea about this how to make it work. NB 7.3

Answer (score 0):

My solution is...

```
// To have access to code completion on Dreamweaver   
$var = false;
if ($var) {
    // this code never runs
    include '../core/utils.php';
}
// Real relative path to work in the server
include 'core/utils.php';
```